# Eliminar el valor de un índice de una lista mediante un input de la posición del valor

Tags: python, python-3.8

Lo que quiero lograr es eliminar un valor que vendría en el input de *e*, la lista es creada aleatoriamente por inputs anteriores.

```
if o == "E":
e = input("¿Qué dato quisieras eliminar? Ingresa el número de ubicación: ") 

if e in Lista:
  Lista.pop(e)
```

Comment: `e` es un string, y `pop()` requiere un entero.

Comment: `Lista.pop(Lista.index(e))`

Comment: `Lista.pop(int(e))`

Comment: @MauricioContreras si esa fuera la solucion, es mejor directamente hacer Lista.remove(e)

Comment: Nota: Eliminar un valor de una lista, la reindexa. Por ejemplo, si tienes una lista de 5 elementos y eliminas el que está en la posición 2, otro valor tomará esa posición. Si solo quieres eliminar el valor, eso no aplica para tu caso; pero si quieres dejar el "hueco", entonces usa una estructura explícitamente indexada, en otras palabras, un diccionario.